# how to use one hive result as condition in another hive query?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a question. I have two hive tables, first one has condition. need dynamically looking for the condition in sec query.
for example
first query:

```
select col1, col2 from table1. will return account = 'abc'
```

in second query, I need to use this as condition for example:

```
select * from table2
where account = 'abc'
```

anybody has some idea? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Apache Hive supports use of a [join](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Joins) to combine rows from multiple tables based on a related column.

In this example, there is an `accounts` table and an `orders` table.  The query uses a join to find all orders corresponding to each account, filtered to just `account1` and `account2`.  The `accounts` table is simplified to just one column in this example, which perhaps makes it look unnecessary.  In real-world usage, an accounts table would have multiple columns, but the join syntax remains the same.

### Query

```
WITH
    accounts AS (
        SELECT 'account1' AS account_name UNION ALL
        SELECT 'account2' AS account_name UNION ALL
        SELECT 'account3' AS account_name
    ),
    orders AS (
        SELECT 'account1' AS account_name, 'order1' AS order_name UNION ALL
        SELECT 'account1' AS account_name, 'order2' AS order_name UNION ALL
        SELECT 'account1' AS account_name, 'order3' AS order_name UNION ALL
        SELECT 'account2' AS account_name, 'order4' AS order_name UNION ALL
        SELECT 'account2' AS account_name, 'order5' AS order_name UNION ALL
        SELECT 'account2' AS account_name, 'order6' AS order_name UNION ALL
        SELECT 'account3' AS account_name, 'order7' AS order_name UNION ALL
        SELECT 'account3' AS account_name, 'order8' AS order_name UNION ALL
        SELECT 'account3' AS account_name, 'order9' AS order_name
    )
SELECT
    orders.account_name,
    orders.order_name
FROM accounts
JOIN orders ON accounts.account_name = orders.account_name
WHERE accounts.account_name IN ('account1', 'account2');
```

### Results

```
    account_name    order_name
0   account1    order1
1   account1    order2
2   account1    order3
3   account2    order4
4   account2    order5
5   account2    order6
```